# what is the formula to set the right value for yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation in cluster

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, ambari

Consider in a scenario where you are setting up a cluster where each machine having 32G GB of RAM. And 16 CPU CORE

How to determine the following parameters according to the info (32G GB of RAM. And 16 CPU CORE
 )

```
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores
```

is it possible to  give here formula to calculate these parameters on any cluster?

As we know Some of this RAM (32G) should be reserved for Operating System and other installed applications.

So we set the - yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb to 28G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera provides a spreadsheet to do this.

http://tiny.cloudera.com/yarn-tuning-guide

You should also look at [Untangling Apache Hadoop YARN, Part 2: Global Configuration Basics](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/10/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-2/)

In general, vcores should be thought of as a computational unit.  If you think your applications will use on average 1GB of RAM, you would set vcores to 28 given 28GB of total memory.  If you think it's 2GB, then 14.

Note: In almost all cases, applications are I/O bound (either disk or network) so CPU overutilization is rarely a limiting factor.

Comment: sorry but not understand "you would set vcores to 28" , we have only 16 CPU CORE , and how application use only 1G?

Comment: Vcores ARE NOT analogous to cpu cores.

Comment: You can always specify heap size via mapreduce parameters.